# Google Mobile Ad SDK Ios7 missing audio framework

Tags: ios7, admob, xcode5, trigger.io

Trying to add Google Mobile Ad SDK to a project and looks like i'm missing a frame work. I've added the `AVfoundation` frame work to the project but still triggering these.

```
Ld /Users/kevzettler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ForgeInspector-hatfxtfbvtjkzgalvydfjjdmgdvi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ForgeInspector.app/ForgeInspector normal i386
    cd /Users/kevzettler/checkiday/forge-admob/inspector/ios-inspector
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 5.0.1
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk -L/Users/kevzettler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ForgeInspector-hatfxtfbvtjkzgalvydfjjdmgdvi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/kevzettler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ForgeInspector-hatfxtfbvtjkzgalvydfjjdmgdvi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/kevzettler/checkiday/forge-admob/inspector/ios-inspector -filelist /Users/kevzettler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ForgeInspector-hatfxtfbvtjkzgalvydfjjdmgdvi/Build/Intermediates/ForgeInspector.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ForgeInspector.build/Objects-normal/i386/ForgeInspector.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -all_load -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=5.0.1 /Users/kevzettler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ForgeInspector-hatfxtfbvtjkzgalvydfjjdmgdvi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libForgeModule.a -framework SystemConfiguration -framework AssetsLibrary -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework ForgeCore -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/kevzettler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ForgeInspector-hatfxtfbvtjkzgalvydfjjdmgdvi/Build/Intermediates/ForgeInspector.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ForgeInspector.build/Objects-normal/i386/ForgeInspector_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/kevzettler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ForgeInspector-hatfxtfbvtjkzgalvydfjjdmgdvi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ForgeInspector.app/ForgeInspector


Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_AVAudioSessionPortBuiltInSpeaker", referenced from:
      -[GADDevice audioRouteUsingAVAudioSession] in libForgeModule.a(GADDevice.o)
  "_AVAudioSessionPortHeadphones", referenced from:
      -[GADDevice audioRouteUsingAVAudioSession] in libForgeModule.a(GADDevice.o)
  "_AudioServicesPlaySystemSound", referenced from:
      -[GADDefaultGMSGHandler didReceiveVibrateNotification:] in libForgeModule.a(GADDefaultGMSGHandler.o)
  "_AudioSessionGetProperty", referenced from:
      -[GADDevice audioRouteUsingAudioToolkit] in libForgeModule.a(GADDevice.o)
  "_AudioSessionInitialize", referenced from:
      -[GADDevice audioRouteUsingAudioToolkit] in libForgeModule.a(GADDevice.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ASIdentifierManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libForgeModule.a(GADDevice.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVAudioSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libForgeModule.a(GADDevice.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MFMailComposeViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libForgeModule.a(GADOpener.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MFMessageComposeViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libForgeModule.a(GADOpener.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKStoreProductViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libForgeModule.a(GADOpener.o)
  "_SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier", referenced from:
      -[GADOpener openInAppStore:fallbackURLString:] in libForgeModule.a(GADOpener.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

frameworks in build phase:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045240/admob-ios7-error-audio-framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `AudioToolbox` framework for those remaining `AVAudioSession...` and `AudioSession...` symbols.

You also need the `StoreKit` and `MessageUI` frameworks for the other symbols.

Comment: Added a screen shot of included frameworks in my build phase looks like I have all those, still getting the error.

Comment: I tried adding AudioUnit.framework, error reduced to 1 but Still getting "Framework not found AudioUnit" error.

Answer (score 0):

Ok looks like the problem was that I am building a module for trigger.io and it has nested xcode projects. I was adding the frameworks to a child project when the parent project was what actually needed them.